Error: TelegramBaseClient.connect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Send error( help
    from telethon import TelegramClient
    import time

    api_id = 
    api_hash = ''
    message = input("Введите сообщение для рассылки")
    file_users = open("users.txt")
    users_list = file_users.readlines()
    time_pause_string = input("Введите задержку между сообщениями (сек)")
    time_pause = int(time_pause_string)

    client = TelegramClient('', api_id, api_hash, system_version='')    

    def send_message_user(client, username, message):
        try:
            client.connect("")
            client.send_message(username, message)
            print(f'Сообщение отправлено пользователю {username}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Ошибка при отправке сообщения: {e}')

    count = 0
    for line in users_list:
        count += 1
        username ="{}".format(line.strip())
        send_message_user(client, username, message)
        print(f'Сообщение отправлено пользователю {username}')
        time.sleep(time_pause)    
    
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(send_message_user())
        print("Сообщения отправлены")

I can’t figure out where the error is in passing arguments?
I'm not very good at async, but maybe that's the problem? or were the def arguments passed incorrectly?
